# Авторизация на сайте через request.post

Tags: python, post

Здравствуйте.

Есть учетная запись на сайте. Нужно написать скрипт для авторизации ( если важно, на Пайтоне) , который через POST-запрос с данными логин/пароль делает эту авторизацию ИЛИ который делает POST-запрос с предварительно сохраненными куками авторизированого пользователя.

**Вопрос 1)**

Есть страница example.com/login . Есть форма авторизации с

```
   action="/xxx/yyy" method="post"
```

Как узнать на какую страницу отправлять запрос? example.com/login/xxx/yyy не работает.

**Вопрос 2)**

Если я хочу решить эту проблему отправкой куков авторизированого пользователя, какие именно куки ( их название), я должен передать в запросе?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: С кукисами +- разобрался. Но проблема - когда я делаю ГЕТ запрос с кукисами ( рабочими ), то сразу после этого запросу кукисы стают неактивными ( то есть в том браузере, откуда я взял эти кукисы и где я был авторизирован, после отправки гет запроса я теряю там авторизацию), можно это как-нибудь обойти?

Comment: Связь cookie-session имеют ограниченное время. Так что надо логинется, затем сохранять куда-то куки и работать с ними пока не будет истечение их срока. 
Посмотреть куда и с какими данными можно через google chrome -> developer tools -> network, предварительно поставил галку Preverse Log.
При логине в списке появится POST запрос со всеми параметрами и урлов запроса.

Comment: @tcpack4, тут как раз проблема в том, что со сроками с куками все ок.

Comment: Возможно, что браузер и скрипт отсылают разные HTTP хэдеры ( например User-Agent ) и сервер дропает старую сессию куков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было передавать cookies через header.

```
import requests as r


header = {
    "Cookie": "тут вставляем куки"
}

response = r.get('ссылка', headers=header)
```